# How do I ensure my winform application deployment overwrites old versions

Tags: c#, winforms, deployment

I have created a msi install package for my project from the VS2008 deployment project. but I am having problems when it comes to upgrading installs, The previously installed version does not get overwritten. How do I ensure that previously installed versions get overwritten?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. In Visual Studio select your Setup project within the Solution Explorer
2. Open the Properties Window

   - **don't right click** and select properties.
   - select View - Properties Window
3. set RemovePreviousVersions to true
4. increment the version to a higher number
5. select yes in the upcoming message box

If you built and deploy this new setup, a setup with an older version number will be deleted.

**Important:** the setup version number is completely independent from your application or assembly version number!

Comment: If only that worked for me!  What do you mean "setup version number is completely independent?"

Comment: @JohnB: Maybe you overlooked the point *select your Setup project* in the first bullet point. If you selected the setup project and look into the properties window you'll find down at the bottom a VersionNumber. This has to be incremented for each built that will be published and this number is independent of the version number of your application and/or assemblies.

Answer (score 12):

*(Oliver's answer is correct, but I wanted to add pictures and some more details)*

Select the setup project in your *solution*, then open the **Properties** pane (the tab next to Toolbox):

[image]

- Make sure `DetectNewerInstalledVersion` is true (it is be default)
- Set `InstallAllUsers` to true
- Set `RemovePreviousVersions` to true
- Update the `Version` number and hit Enter
- After you hit enter, Visual Studio will ask if you want to generate a new GUID for `ProductCode`, click yes

Additionally, you need to update the version numbers for each *project* in your *solution*, because the installer will only replace *DLLs* if their version number has been incremented:

- Open each project's **AssemblyInfo.cs** and update the `AssemblyVersion` and `AssemblyFileVersion` numbers

Or a better way:

- Remove `AssemblyVersion` and `AssemblyFileVersion` lines from each *project's* **AssemblyInfo.cs**
- Link to a **VersionInfo.cs** file in your *solution* with those 2 lines
- *Step-by-step for the above: [The Right Way To Version Your Assemblies](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/328977/The-Right-Way-to-Version-Your-Assemblies)*

Right-click on the setup project and select **Properties** (a different *Properties* dialog):

- Set **Windows Installer 4.5** as a **Prerequisite** instead of the Visual Studio default of **Windows Installer 3.1**

I'm not sure if all of these steps are necessary, and there may be other ways to set this up, but the above steps work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Installer has built in checks on your files to make sure that the version is higher than the previous version of that file.  If it is not, Windows Installer will not overwrite it.  For more extensive info on how Windows Installer handles versioning check out this MSDN article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368599%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

We need to set REINSTALLMODE property of our msi file to amus.

Following is the link to know more about the meaning of 'amus'
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371182%28VS.85%29.aspx

There are two ways to do that.

1. By using msiexec.exe which comes with .NET SDK (if you have VS 2005 or VS 2008 it will come with it, just browse to command prompt of visual studio and you will find it there)

once you find msiexec.exe just type following command to set REINSTALLMODE property to amus for your installer.

msiexec.exe /i foo.msi REINSTALLMODE=amus