# Setup project with autoupdate feature vs2010

Tags: c#, setup-project, setup-deployment

I have created a setup project in visual studio. It works fine, now when i make some changes, create new setup file and then try to execute it. It gives me this error.

[image]

I don't want user to bother with this step. I want it to update the application or uninstall it first and then install new  version.

How could i do this.

Kindly guide.

Comment: Here's a step-by-step answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221762/how-do-i-ensure-my-winform-application-deployment-overwrites-old-versions/19548387#19548387

Comment: @JohnB Incredible, Thanks a lot. I was still messing with this thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Installer automatically uninstalls the old version if you increase your package [ProductVersion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370859%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and change the [ProductCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370854%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This can be done in the project Properties pane.

If you don't do this, you need to uninstall your old package manually using the Control Panel applet.