# Install and Uninstall window service using visual studio 2013 installer project

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, windows-services

I have created an installer of windows service using visual studio 2013 installer project. I want a functionality like whenever I make a new installer and install that, then old service should be uninstalled and new one should get installed. But it is not happening as my expectations. System gives a message like "Same application or service is already installed." How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever u are looking for it can achievable by using the setup and deployment in Visual studion u have to create the MSI Package or setup.exe from there when ever you build a windows service. you can get more information http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/996353/create-setup-and-deployment-project-in-visual-studio-200820/

[How to make the msi overwrite program if a previous version exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12211193/how-to-make-the-msi-overwrite-program-if-a-previous-version-exist)